# Two chef nodes (two environments) on one machine

Tags: chef

We are resource limited here, and want our qa and staging environments on one machine.

We are going to run separate binaries and confs for our app & supporting services.

According to chef docs it is possible to have a single machine be two nodes.  It just never explains how.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to execute chef client with an alternative configuration. The default config file and directory is /etc/chef/client.rb. You could use that one for one of the nodes / environments. Let's assume that will be "staging". You should probably make sure the node and environment are set up for the proper values:

```
node_name "mynode.staging"
environment "staging"
```

The other you could create such as /etc/chef/qa/client.rb for your qa configuration. In order to avoid conflict, you'll need to change the various configuration values for Chef that point in /etc/chef, and /var/chef.

See the [Chef Configuration Settings](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings) wiki page for a complete list of configuration settings you can modify.

You should use the node_name and environment values similar to the staging environment. When you run chef, specify the alternative configuration file.

`chef-client -c /etc/chef/qa/client.rb`

Comment: Thanks, I'd upvote but I don't have enough repuation on this site yet.  Much appreciated!!